# one entrance for loop in threading

Tags: python-2.7, pthreads, pyqt4, raspbian

I am using pyqt4 , python2.7. opencv3 , raspbian
I create Function with name Vision_thread()to search faces in every frame. and create funcation with name start_thread() to execute Vision_thread()Function by thread. look here:

```
def start_thread():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=Vision_thread)
    t1.start()
    #t1.join()
```

now I call Funcation by button created by PYqt4 as way:

```
self.pushButtonStart.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Vision", None))
         # program event click for start Vision button
        self.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(start_thread)
```

my problem is : when click on button . the loop in function Vision_thread() execute for first entrance only . and do not continuous .
but when I write:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=Vision_thread())
```

insted of

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=Vision_thread)
```

the function Vision_thread() execute without any problem . but this is no thread . 
what is problem??????
Vision_thread() code is :

```
def Vision_thread():

        print("Vision")
        print (search)
        GPIO.output(32,True)

        for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
              image = frame.array
              gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
              faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
              for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                  cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                  face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                  face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))
                  #Try to recognize the face
                  prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
                  cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                  x_left=160
                  if prediction[1]<500:
                      cv2.putText(image,'%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),(x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
                      if names[prediction[0]]==search:
                          x_left = x-width
                          x_right = width - w - x
                          sum_final=x_left+x_right

                          if x_left>180:
                              Left_thread()


                          if x_left<140:
                            Right_thread()


                          print "left={0}\nright={1}\nsum={2}".format(x_left, x_right,sum_final)

                  else:
                     cv2.putText(image,'not recognized',(x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))

              cv2.imshow('OpenCV', image)
              key = cv2.waitKey(10)
              rawCapture.truncate(0)

              if key == 27:
                GPIO.output(32,False)
                break
```